# C# - Watermark passwordchar?

Tags: c#, winforms, watermark

I'm currently making a login form to my program where I have a watermark for the two textboxes Email and Password.

When a textbox is empty, its watermark text will appear in it like "Enter email here" and "Enter password here".

My code so far is:

```
    private void emailLogin_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e){
        if (emailLogin.Text.Length == 0){
            emailLogin.Text = "Email";
            emailLogin.ForeColor = Color.Silver;
        }
    }

    private void emailLogin_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e){
        if (emailLogin.Text == "Email"){
            emailLogin.Text = "";
            emailLogin.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }

    private void passwordLogin_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e){
        if (passwordLogin.Text.Length == 0){
            passwordLogin.Text = "Password";
            passwordLogin.ForeColor = Color.Silver;
        }
    }

    private void passwordLogin_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e){
        if (passwordLogin.Text == "Password"){
            passwordLogin.Text = "";
            passwordLogin.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }
```

But now my problem is that I want to use password characters for the password.
But I still want the watermark text to be in regular text.
When I check to use a password char it turns my watermark into "********" instead of "Password". How can I fix that?

By the way, I don't want to use the "UseSystemPasswordChar" (those dots). I want to use "PasswordChar" and use asterisks (*) as password chars.

Comment: Could you add a tag to state whether this question is Windows Forms or WPF related please.

Comment: In WPF, Textbox has Foreground property not ForeColor. So it's Windows Forms

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just set it and unset it as you do for the ForeColor :

```
    private void passwordLogin_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e){
        if (passwordLogin.Text.Length == 0){
            passwordLogin.Text = "Password";
            passwordLogin.ForeColor = Color.Silver;
            passwordLogin.PasswordChar = '\0';
        }
    }

    private void passwordLogin_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e){
        if (passwordLogin.Text == "Password"){
            passwordLogin.Text = "";
            passwordLogin.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            passwordLogin.PasswordChar = '*';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you so much! I did not know about the \0. What exactly does it mean? Again, thank you so much! :)

Comment: @user3036459 `\0` is just the null character, i.e. nothing.

Comment: So it was that easy, haha! I was trying to figure this out for a good 45 minutes. Thanks! :)

Comment: \0 is not really 'nothing' - it's just that the PasswordChar property treats zero as having the special meaning of 'don't display password masking'